# Second Subquery reference to parent-parent query: column not found

Tags: mysql, subquery

Is there a limit of subquerys where the referencing outer column is working on?

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    `userouter`.`id` AS `user_id`
FROM
    `users` AS `userouter`
WHERE
    123456 = (
        SELECT
            SUM(`tmp`.`sum`) AS `sum_total`
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    SUM(`invoiceposition`.`number` * `invoiceposition`.`amount`) AS `sum`
                FROM
                    `invoices` AS `invoice` INNER JOIN
                    `invoicepositions` AS `invoiceposition` ON
                        `invoice`.`id` = `invoiceposition`.`invoice`
                WHERE
                    `invoice`.`user` = `userouter`.`id`
                GROUP BY
                    `invoice`.`id`
            ) AS `tmp`
    )
GROUP BY
    `userouter`.`id`
```

And i get `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'userouter.id' in 'where clause'`

How can i reference the `userouter.id` in the sub-sub query?

Comment: You can't reference that column because it's not within the scope of the subquery. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, so consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sorry but i can not publish the database structure or data to the web. but please give me a clue why u told its `not within the scope of the subquery` - this will may help me to get rid of my problem

Comment: everything between the perenthesis is it's own scope. if you can't run the subquery all by itself then it's not going to work as a subquery.

Comment: also the outer `where` part doesn't reference the table at all.. might as well just do `where 1`..

Comment: Yeah, seems like double nested subqueries do not have the reference of the outer query :-( - also the function "WITH ROLLUP" does not work, becouse i would have to use a parent query to get only the rollup result.. seems not ossible the way i try - i will look for another way, thanks for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  it seems in a normal way not possible to resolve the problem (double nested subquery reference to outer query), i now solved the problem by creating a mysql function with the user id as parameter.

hope this will help other searchers

Answer (score -1):

Remove the double nesting.

```
SELECT
    `userouter`.`id` AS `user_id`
FROM
    `users` AS `userouter`
LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    `invoice`.`user` as `user_id`, SUM(`invoiceposition`.`number` * `invoiceposition`.`amount`) AS `sum`
                FROM
                    `invoices` AS `invoice` INNER JOIN
                    `invoicepositions` AS `invoiceposition` ON
                        `invoice`.`id` = `invoiceposition`.`invoice`
                WHERE
                    `invoice`.`user` = `userouter`.`id`
                GROUP BY
                    `invoice`.`id`
            ) AS `tmp`
ON `tmp`.`user_id` = `userouter`.`id`
WHERE
    123456 = `userouter`.`id`
GROUP BY
    `userouter`.`id`
```

Comment: this produces the same error, anymway, thanks for your effort